mysql is getting long lock while adding foreign key column as nullable and no default value with index on a big table
I am running Laravel Migration and this is how it looks on terminals
adding a column state_id on the click table which contains millions of records. state_id is nullable and has no default value with an index set on it
2024_04_29_125513_add_state_id_column_to_click_table
Schema::table('click', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('state_id')->nullable()->constrained('state')->after('country_id');
    });

This is how the raw query looks like
ALTER TABLE click
ADD COLUMN state_id INT UNSIGNED NULL AFTER country_id
ADD CONSTRAINT click_state_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (state_id) REFERENCES state(id)
ADD INDEX click_state_id_index (state_id);

and even breaking this query into 3 steps like
1- adding column with nullable value 
2- adding foreign key constraint 
3- adding index 

is still keeping a long lock when I just add the nullable column.
How do we not lock table while running migration.
this is how click table look like
CREATE TABLE click (
  id bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  uuid char(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  placement_id bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  category_id bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  vertical_id bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  advertiser_id bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  campaign_id bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  lander_id bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  publisher_id bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  traffic_source_id bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  traffic_type_id bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  sub_source_id bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  platform_id bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  operating_system_id bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  country_id bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  external_id varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  ip varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  url text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  click_out_url text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  referer varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  bid decimal(8, 4) DEFAULT NULL,
  revenue varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  payout varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  position int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  utm_source varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  utm_medium varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  iso_code varchar(5) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  country varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  city varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  state varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  postal_code varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  lat decimal(9, 6) DEFAULT NULL,
  lon decimal(9, 6) DEFAULT NULL,
  timezone varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  device varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  device_name varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  platform varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  platform_version varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  is_robot tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  robot_name varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  browser varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  browser_version varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  ua varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  footprint varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  algo_id tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  campaign_pool_size int DEFAULT NULL,
  status tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  created_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  updated_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  state_id bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY click_uuid_created_at_updated_at_index (uuid, created_at, updated_at),
  KEY click_created_at_index (created_at),
  KEY click_updated_at_index (updated_at),
  KEY click_uuid_index (uuid),
  KEY click_placement_id_index (placement_id),
  KEY click_category_id_index (category_id),
  KEY click_vertical_id_index (vertical_id),
  KEY click_advertiser_id_index (advertiser_id),
  KEY click_campaign_id_index (campaign_id),
  KEY click_lander_id_index (lander_id),
  KEY click_publisher_id_index (publisher_id),
  KEY click_traffic_source_id_index (traffic_source_id),
  KEY click_traffic_type_id_index (traffic_type_id),
  KEY click_sub_source_id_index (sub_source_id),
  KEY click_platform_id_index (platform_id),
  KEY click_country_id_index (country_id),
  KEY click_external_id_index (external_id),
  KEY click_algo_id_index (algo_id),
  KEY click_status_index (status),
  KEY click_operating_system_id_index (operating_system_id),
  CONSTRAINT click_advertiser_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (advertiser_id) REFERENCES client (id),
  CONSTRAINT click_campaign_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (campaign_id) REFERENCES campaign (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT click_category_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES category (id),
  CONSTRAINT click_country_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES country (id),
  CONSTRAINT click_lander_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (lander_id) REFERENCES lander (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT click_placement_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (placement_id) REFERENCES placement (id),
  CONSTRAINT click_platform_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (platform_id) REFERENCES platform (id),
  CONSTRAINT click_publisher_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (publisher_id) REFERENCES client (id),
  CONSTRAINT click_sub_source_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (sub_source_id) REFERENCES sub_source (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT click_traffic_source_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (traffic_source_id) REFERENCES traffic_source (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT click_traffic_type_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (traffic_type_id) REFERENCES traffic_source_type (id),
  CONSTRAINT click_vertical_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (vertical_id) REFERENCES vertical (id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 48845998 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci



Why not wait for the migration to finish and then run the seeder? How is the state table not linked to click table (you are making a constrained FK to it in the migration)?

yes agree with that. but when I just add a column without a foreign key and add it as nullable it takes still do long lock on table! so primary question is how to make migration without locking table ?

I am very ignorant about databases, but from my understanding, you are adding a foreign key/index, it will for sure lock the table, and I think you cannot go around it, because it is generating an index and a FK, it must be locked, else you get things out of sync or not correctly done, how can you add an index if you allow someone to alter something while doing it? makes no sense (for data integrity -> correct indexes)
